# Issues with YouTube and Vimeo Embed Code on iPhone 3Gs

Tags: ios, youtube, vimeo

I'm working on an iPhone app that includes Vimeo and YouTube videos through a WebView and the respective embed codes.  The videos work fine in iPhone 4 and 4S, but have issues on iPhone 3GS.  The error provided on the 3GS has to do with the H.264 encoding.

I did a bit of research on the subject since I am not too familiar with H.264.  It appears that the 3GS only supports the H.264 baseline profile whereas the 4 and 4S support the main profile.

Does anybody have experience with this issue?  I'm guessing there isn't an easy work-around.  Is H.264 main profile the standard for both Vimeo and YouTube, or does it depend on how the user uploads the video?